# No template names provided

Tags: python, django, queryset

Получаю ошибку из заголовка при попытке передать в шаблон посчитанный queryset из метода get_queryset() в ListView:

Я пытаюсь получить 10 последних записей из бд с сохранением сортировки способом, подобным [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555673/django-query-get-last-n-records):

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = Message.objects.filter(Target_id=self.dialog)
    qs = qs.order_by('-id')[:10][::-1]
    return qs
```

Без [::-1] все работает. Пробовал [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495586/how-do-i-get-the-last-n-objects-of-a-django-query) же

```
    qs = reversed(qs.order_by('-id')[:10])
```

и даже просто

```
    qs = list(qs.order_by('-id')[:10])
```

- при любой попытке вычислить queryset до шаблона натыкаюсь на `TemplateDoesNotExist`. Что я делаю не так?

PS: django 1.11

Comment: Отрицательный шаг не работает с queryset'ами. Используйте [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by).

Comment: только для среза в django 1.11.11 не работает order_by

Comment: @ZaArs срез - это терминальная операция. Надо сначала сортировать, а потом срезать. Так работает и в 1.11, и даже в 1.1 работало.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev , ему сначала надо отсортировать, потом забрать 10 записей, а потом снова отсортировать. Поэтому я и говорю, что не сработает. Спасибо, что пояснили мои слова, почему не сработает.

Comment: @ZaArs и правда, я невнимателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, вам поможет разворот в шаблоне:

```
{% for obj in object_list reversed %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Это работает, как надо. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Для срезов Queryset'а в Django 1.11.11 не работает order_by. Это фича 2.+

Если вы используете postgresql как БД, то есть решение с аннотациями [RawSQL](https://smyt.ru/blog/django-orm/) и [row number](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/)

Примерно это будет выглядеть так

```
queryset = Message.objects.filter(
    Target_id=self.dialog
).annotate(
    row_num=RawSQL(
        'ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY -id)'
    )
).filter(row_num__lte=10)

# .filter(row_num__lte=10) можно заменить на order_by('row_num')[:10]
```

Comment: Вероятно, в вашем ответе есть доля истины, но ответы на so.com, ссылки на которые я привел в заголовке и на которых изначально ориентировался, были даны в 15-16 годах, когда django 2.x еще не было - и судя по количеству оценок, это прекрасно работало на младших версиях django.

Comment: Мне захотелось разрешить этот казус. Я проверил, и оказалось, что конструкция `qs.order_by('-id')[:10][::-1]` прекрасно работает, если не использовать cbv. Видимо, корень моей проблемы крылся где-то в недрах `ListView`